# Can I get the value of application/x-www-form-urlencoded with @Getmapping?

Tags: spring-boot

I need to use @GetMapping to get the value of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
However, I can't get it and it is null.
Of course it succeeds with @PostMapping.
If you know how to do this, please let me know.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/sample")
    public String getSample(@ModelAttribute("param") SampleRequest request) {

        return request.getParam();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MultiValueMap` to achieve this. However, I am not sure whether this conforms with the best practices of REST.

Below is a code snips that works.

```
    @GetMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getUrlEncoded(
            @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> model
    ) {
        System.out.println(model.get("name"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Success");
    }
```

[image: Postman request]

Console output

```
2021-12-04 19:42:07.856  INFO 23352 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-12-04 19:42:07.856  INFO 23352 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-12-04 19:42:07.857  INFO 23352 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
[chait]
```